# Swift displays Optional( prefix in UILabel, after getting string from network. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift

I've started to learn Swift. And I want to make a test network request, get some data and display in UILabel just to test how it works. I use the following code function to achieve this:

```
func readSomeTextFromInternet() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://azazai.com/api/getEventsList?limit=10&offset=0");

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            _ = error.debugDescription;
            if (data == nil) {
                return;
            }

            let str = String(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding));

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.labelText.text = str;
            }
        }

        task.resume();
    }
```

I've read about optionals and tried many different combinations with ? and !. But it always displays this Optional( prefix. How to remove this prefix?

I've tried this code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if let string = str {
                    self.labelText.text = string;
                }
            }
```

But It raises an error: Error:(53, 20) initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'. It says, that it's not optional. But it displays Optional( prefix WTF?

[image]

Comment: What you need is "optional binding". Explained in this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: Thank You. I've tried optional binding, but it raises an error!

Comment: You're declaring "str" like this: `let str:String!`, it is an "implicitly unwrapped optional", not a normal optional. Don't do that. Remove the `:String!` part.

Comment: And there's a lot of forced-unwrapped optionals in your code. *Don't do that.* Read carefully the link I've provided in my first comment and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: I've tried this code: let str:String? = String(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)); And this code let str = String(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)); It displays optional prefix

Comment: Argh... I never told you to do `let str:String?`. I just told you to *remove* the `:String!` part. :)

Comment: I've tried many variants. But it still shows this Optional( prefix

Comment: Read the whole chapter I linked from the documentation. Learn about Optionals properly. This is **very** important for a Swift programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix and a few suggestions:

Do not use forced-unwrapping, use optional binding instead.

Example for your question:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://azazai.com/api/getEventsList?limit=10&offset=0") {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
        if let data = data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.labelText.text = str
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Do not add `;` at the end of expressions.

Do not use nested constructs as `String(NSString(...))` when there's no reason to do it.

Do not ignore error variables.

Do read and learn about Optionals properly, there's no excuse not to do it when programming in Swift.

Comment: Thank you for help! Another question:  NSUrl returns optional. So an error can occur while its construction. How can I get this error info, if it occurs?

Comment: You're welcome. But the convention on SO is to have *one* question per page. Ask a new question if you have a new problem, we'll be here to help you. This one has been solved and should be let alone now. :)